# For a ring $R$ and ideals $I$ and $J$, if $I\subset J$ and $R/I\subset R/J$ then $I=J$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm going a little crazy over whether this is true or not; it feels right but I don't trust it since I haven't seen it stated explicitly.

My sketch of the proof:

$I\subset J\Rightarrow R/J\subset R/I$

Thus $R/J=R/I$ which means

$x\in J \Leftrightarrow x=0\in R/J \Leftrightarrow x=0 \in R/I \Leftrightarrow x\in I$

Am I missing something here?

Comment: $I\subset J$ doesn't imply $R/J\subset R/I$, it implies $R/J$ is a quotient of $R/I$. You should be more explicit about what $R/I\subset R/J$ means since these aren't canonically subsets of the same set. Do you mean the natural map $R/I\to R/J$ is injective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense it is correct, minus the foundational question about what $R/I \subset R/J$ means if $I \neq J$ since these are not comparable sets if $I$ and $J$ are different ideals. This is so since $R/I$ is the set of cosets $r + I$ and for a coset of $R/I$ to be in $R/J$ means that $r + I = r' + J$ for some $r'$, but moving the $r'$ over and noting that $I$ and $J$ are subgroups gives that $r - r' \in I$ and so $I = J$. So, the statement trivially implies that they are equal.

Maybe a statement that makes sense but is (edited not true) is that $R/I$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R/J$ instead of actually a subgroup. Then the parallel formulation of your argument is that of the correspondence theorem given by the last part of Theorem 3.3 of http://math.harvard.edu/~xwang/LectureNotes.pdf gives that $R/J\times J/I \cong R/I$. So, $R/J \times J/I$ has a homomorphism onto $R/J$ and onto $R/I$, but that does not necessitate anything, as stated in a comment correcting this response.

Comment: I don't think your modified statement is true. If $R=F[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ is a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables, $I=\langle x_1\rangle$ and $J=\langle x_1,x_2\rangle$ then $R/I$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R/J$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I fixed it.